# Platform versus deployment target in .podspec for Cocoapd

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm pretty sure this is an obvious question, but what is the difference in a Cocoapod .podspec between `platform` and `deployment_target`? For example:

```
  s.platform     = :ios, "8.0"
  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
```

In my usual understanding of deployment target, I take that to mean the oldest version of iOS that I'm wanting my app to run on. But what about platform?

Thanks.

Comment: "As opposed to the `platform` attribute, the `deployment_target` attribute allows to specify multiple platforms on which this pod is supported — specifying a different deployment target for each." https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#deployment_target ?

Comment: So you don't need platform if you use deployment_target?

Comment: what if we just use "platform : ios" with no ios number ?